# Strange Closure Compiler issue

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I'm using Google's Closure Compiler in advanced mode, and I'm having a strange issue. Here is the uncompiled code, with returned log statement from the compiled version running:

```
goog.provide('frame.store');

goog.require('frame.storeBack.LocalStore');
goog.require('frame.storeBack.Mem');

frame.store = (function() {
    /** prioritised list of backends **/
    var backends = [
        frame.storeBack.LocalStore,
        frame.storeBack.Mem
    ];

    frame.log(backends); 
    // [function rc(){}, function tc(){this.q={}}]

    frame.log(frame.storeBack.LocalStore === backends[0]); 
    // true

    frame.log(frame.storeBack.LocalStore.isAvailable === backends[0].isAvailable); 
    // false

    frame.log(frame.storeBack.LocalStore.isAvailable);
    // function sc(){try{return"localStorage"in window&&window.localStorage!==k}catch(a){return l}}

    frame.log(backends[0].isAvailable);
    // undefined

    for (var i=0, len=backends.length; i<len; i++)
        if (backends[i].isAvailable())
            return new backends[i]();
    // Uncaught TypeError: Object function rc(){} has no method 'Ga'

    throw('no suitable storage backend');
})();
```

For some reason the static method isAvailable is not present when LocalStore is accessed via the backends array, and is present when it's accessed via it's global namespace.

Can anyone see why?

EDIT: for reference, here is the method declaration:

```
frame.storeBack.LocalStore.isAvailable = function() {
    try {
        return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null;
    }catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn on `--debug true` to check your output and what `frame.storeBack.LocalStore.isAvailable` is renamed to.

Dump a variables name map to check whether `frame.storeBack.LocalStore.isAvailable` has been flattened.

For example, the Closure Compiler **may** flatten `frame.storeBack.LocalStore.isAvailable` first to `frame$storeBack$LocalStore$isAvailable`, then rename the whole thing to the global function "a" or something.  This is called flattening of namespaces.  Check the debug output to see whether your function declaration has been renamed to:

```
$frame$storeBack$LocalStore$isAvailable$$ = function() {
```

In such case, calling `frame.storeBack.LocalStore.isAvailable()` directly will still call the flattened global version, no prob here!  However, you can't expact that `isAvailable()` exists in `frame.storeBack.LocalStore` (another object) any more.  In the compiled output, `frame.storeBack.LocalStore.isAvailable` and `frame.storeBack.LocalStore` are now separated.  This is the behavior of the compiler's namespace flattening, *if it happens*.

You're asking for trouble putting properties into a constructor function itself -- the compiler does a lot of optimizations on classes that you may not expect.

Check the debug output and variable names map to confirm.  You may have to remove the closure wrapper function in order to see the actual names in the map file.

Comment: Awesome, this was totally it. I didn't realize that putting methods on the constructor could cause these types of problems. I'll watch out for it in the future.

Comment: No prob, @defrex.  The Closure Compiler demands a lot from you, but the results are usually worth it!

Comment: In the Closure Compiler, if ever something doesn't work after compiling, it is usually "optimizations happen".  The trick is to know when it happens...

Comment: @defrex, a bit more info.  The Compiler doesn't know that you are accessing the property "isAvailable" *indirectly* via another variable (called an "alias").  In *Advanced Mode*, whenever it doesn't know something, it closes its eyes and assumes it isn't there.  Then it merrily optimizes away.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your back ends are exactly...
But shouldn't you instantiate them?

```
var backends = { localStore : new frame.storeBack.LocalStore(),
                 mem:         new frame.storeBack.Mem() };
```

Comment: I do, in the loop: return new backends[i]();

Comment: To clarify, isAvailable is a static method. It's a method on the constructor, not the prototype.

Comment: Oh sorry.  I see what you mean.  Hmmm.  The static method is not available, but the prototype methods are available?  That to me implies that the static method may be defined at a higher level than the LocalStore for example.  Static methods do not get inherited down the class heirarchy.  See: http://justjs.org/js-oop/static-methods-in-javascript/

Comment: It's not inherited. I added it to the question so you can see.

Comment: Hmm interesting.  I can't explain that.